# Example of a manually written Tab Bar iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I have an application I'm working on that needs to feel somewhat like a Tab Bar application, but without the tab bar.

Anyway I'm wondering if someone has manually written such an application that I can use to bootstrap my knowledge in this area?

Essentially I want to make a tab bar application using a UIToolbar and with some animations

EDIT: I mean with code

Basically I just want a UIToolbar at the bottom and be able to click buttons on it and have the main view flip in and out.

Answer (score 0):

a tab bar application but without the tabs?

you mean, you'd like to have a bunch of embedded UIViewControllers that you just scroll horizontally?